# empty POST results of an LI

Tags: django

I have the following form using the POST method.

```
  <form action = "{% url 'submittedupdate' %}" form method = "POST">
      {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="well">
    <h4 style="margin-top: 0"><strong>Update Application(s)</strong></h4>


        {% for app in applicationaccess %}

            <li name = "report_id" value = "{{app.report_id}}">{{ app.report_name_sc }}</li>

        {% endfor %}

</div>

</form>
```

The current form displays the data correctly, but when I try to retrieve the request in the next view with

```
currlist = request.POST.getlist('report_id')
print(currlist)
```

I get an empty list.

In the previous view applicationaccess is defined as reportaccess shown below:

```
owner = ADMirror.objects.get (employeentname=request.POST.get('userpost'))

    currentaccess = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = 'owner.employeentname, active = 1).values_list('sr_datareduce_summary_code', flat = True).distinct()

    reportIds = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = 'owner.employeentname).values_list('report_id', flat=True)
    currentcheckedlist = request.POST.getlist('current_report')
    reportaccess = QvReportList.objects.filter(report_id__in= currentcheckedlist).values('report_id','report_name_sc').distinct()
```

What is strange is for the other items in the same POST i'm able to pull them in.

Why am I getting an empty list and how can I get the values from report_id in the for loop above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any form data to POST - you are rendering your list as a series of `<li>` elements, but those will not come through in POST. You should modify the `<li>` to include a hidden input with the data you want:

```
<li>
    <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="{{app.report_id}}">
    {{ app.report_name_sc }}
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you Dan, that was exactly it.